# Passing attribute to definition's template in Chef

Tags: apache, chef-infra

I've installed apache2 on my virtual server using the community [apache2 cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/apache2). Then I wanted to create virtual host and I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575314/494468). In a nutshell I have a small cookbook, with recipe like this:

```
include_recipe "apache2"

web_app "my-site" do
  server_name "my-site.localhost"
  server_aliases ["www.my-site.localhost"]
  docroot "/vagrant"
end
```

and a template `templates/default/web_app.conf.erb` containing virtual host settings. The template contains a lot of `@params[:something]` variables. I would like to set the variable `@params[:directory_options]` to `Indexes` to allow file listing. How can I do that? I tried keys like `params` or adding something to attributes, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is use the parameter's name. The same way you set up docroot you can set the other varibles:

```
web_app 'vagrant' do
  server_name 'v.l'
  server_aliases ['www.v.l']
  docroot '/var/www/'
  directory_options 'FollowSymLinks Indexes'
end
```

Comment: Please consider marking your own answer as correct once time allows.